# Почему не работает программа по занесению в большее число одного значения, в меньшее - другого?

Tags: c, float, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{

    float a, b;
    printf("Введите два числа: ");
    scanf("%f%f", &a, &b);

    if ( a > b ) {
    a = fabs ( a + b );
    b = fabs ( 0.5 * ( a - b ));
    }

    else { 
    if ( a < b ) {
    b = fabs ( a + b );
    a = fabs ( 0.5 * ( a - b ));
    }

    if ( a == b )
    printf ("Числа равные");
    }

    printf("a = %g, b= %g", a, b);

    getch();
}
```

Выдаёт: 
[image: 5и2.png]

Comment: А в чем, собственно, ошибка? Что не так?

Comment: Для чисел с плавающей точкой используйте `fabs` (функция `abs` работает для целых чисел). Ну и числа с плавающей точкой, полученные разными путями используйте сравнение на примерное равенство через `fabs(a - b) < epsilon`, как в ответе по ссылке в конце вопроса.

Comment: @Эникейщик См. код: вводим 5 и 2 - получается 1-ый if - переменная a работает правильно, b - неправильно: должно быть 0.5...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему float делится на float, а получается не то?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/895038/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-float-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-float-%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be)

Comment: @0xdb Да не дубликат, я уже редактировал с подробным комментарием, объясняющим это. Там про вспомогательную переменную, а тут про fabs. Единственное, что общее - это код...

Comment: @0xdb Хотя да, сейчас заметил: по смыслу можно их объединить, но друг без друга оно не должно быть.

Comment: @0xdb Отредактировал вопрос так, чтобы оба имели разный смысл. Первичная проблема была - отсутствие вспомогательных переменных. Вторичная проблема возникла - был создан другой вопрос.

Comment: Если уж вы настаиваете на использовании типа `float` (что само по себе странная идея), то правильной функцией является `fabsf`. Не `fabs`, а `fabsf`.

Comment: У вас так и задумано, что второй if работает со значениями, поменявшимися в первом if? Или все таки там нужен else?

Comment: @AnT Да, нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В каждом if первая используемая переменная присваивает первоначальное значение, а вторая - использует первую, уже изменённую.
Т.е. берём 5 и 2 - получаем: a = 7, b = abs (0.5* (7 - 2)) = 2
, а не b = abs (0.5* (5 - 2))...

Выход - использовать временную переменную, вот так:

```
if ( a > b ) {
    a1 = a;
    a = abs ( a1 + b );
    b = abs ( 0.5 * ( a1 - b ));
    }
```

Это центральная ошибка.