# Почему float делится на float, а получается не то?

Tags: c, float, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Почему float делится на float, записывается во float, а получается не float?
Если уж на то пошло, вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{

    double a, b, a1, b1;
    printf("Введите два числа: ");
    scanf("%f%f", &a, &b);

    if ( a > b ) {
    a1 = a;
    a = abs ( a1 + b );
    b = abs ( 0.5 * ( a1 - b ));
    }

    if ( a < b ) {
    b1 = b;
    b = abs ( a + b1 );
    a = abs ( 0.5 * ( a - b ));
    }

    if ( a == b )
    printf ("Числа равные");

    printf("a = %f, b= %f", a, b);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот такое выдаёт:
[image: bug.png]

Что ни говори, 1 - это вам не 1.5

(Про %g я знаю, кстати).

Comment: а где собственно деление?

Comment: @Санаев Ну, *0.5 - то же, что /2

Comment: Не дубликат: см. мои последнии комментарии к вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/895007/В-чём-здесь-ошибка

Comment: **Не дубликат**.Два разных вопроса и даже **ответы тоже разные**.  Этот вопрос про fabs вместо abs, тот вопрос - про необходимость вспомогательных переменных. В ходе решения возникло последовательно две проблемы - последовательно было задано два вопроса...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция abs() возвращает модуль целого числа, поэтому дробная часть отбрасывается. используйте fabs()

Answer (score 4):

В стандартной библиотеке языка С функция вычисления абсолютного значения для типа `float` называется `fabsf`, а не `abs`.

P.S. И не `fabs`! Если вы уж зачем-то взялись использовать тип `float` в своем коде, то именно `fabsf`.

Comment: Дался Вам этот fabsf... Читал, что fabs даже б**о**льшую точность имеет. Вещественные числа - почему бы нет - какой резон в данной задаче избегать их? Тогда надо double, по Вашему - что ж... Хотя [вот тут](http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/math.h/fabs.php?alias=fabsf) нашёл пример: поразительно, но для переменной float number берётся fabs.

Comment: @Олег Остапчук: Во-первых, по вашей ссылке располагается т.наз. "пионэрский гамнокод". Таких сайтов сейчас как собак. Во-вторых, о каком "избегании вещественных чисел" вы ведете речь? Мы говорим о `float` и `double` - никакого "избегания" тут нет.  В-третьих, тип `float` предназначен для экономии памяти при массовом хранении данных. В "обычном" коде его быть не должно (почти). В "обычном" локальном коде должен использоваться `double` (и `fabs`). Но если уже вам приспичило вести вычисления в `float` (почему - это у вас надо спрашивать), то тогда без вариантов  - `fabsf` и именно `fabsf`.

Comment: А экономить память разве не стоит всегда?) И что такое "локальный код"?

Comment: @Олег Остапчук: "Локальный код" - код, работающий с локальными переменными, т.е. переменными, которые имеют *короткое* время жизни. Никакого смысла в экономии памяти на локальных переменных нет (пока вы не начинаете объявлять какие-то огромные локальные массивы). Большинство из этих переменных вообще не будет занимать памяти, ибо будет жить в регистрах процессора. В лучшем случае такая "экономия" не даст вообще ничего, а в худшем - только помешает оптимизации кода.

Comment: Для double не %f, похоже...

Comment: @Олег Остапчук: Для `double` - `%lf`.